# Travel (with public transportation) in New England

Tags: usa, public-transport, hiking, hitchhiking, new-england

I am planning to travel a bit around in New England.

**Myself**: I'm a 28 yo guy and I'll be travelling alone;

**Period**: From the 15th of May for about a week or two;

**Transportation**: I don't have a valid driving licence with me, so my only options are public transports or hitch-hiking.

**Interests**: I would like to avoid big cities and over touristy  stuff. Ideally I would like to see some nature and maybe even hike a bit (with the limitation that I don't have much hiking gear with me) and/or small characteristic towns.

Any recommendation? My main concern is about transportation. Is it doable to reach nice nature places without a car?

Comment: [Concord Coach Lines](https://concordcoachlines.com/) has service to rural New Hampshire and Maine directly [from Logan](https://concordcoachlines.com/stop/logan-airport-boston/), so there are so many options open to you I hardly know where to begin.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that looks like an answer to me. Please post it as one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the info! Do you have any particular destination in mind?

Comment: At this stage in your planning, you should be consulting guide books, travel blogs, tourism websites, and the like to get an idea of the geography, time, and budget involved, as your question is exceptionally broad; there are hundreds of "characteristic towns" to choose from, various bus companies with many overlapping route networks, geography ranging from Connecticut seaside to Vermont mountains to Maine woods. I would say a week is too short for "New England" without a car; you will spend all your time on highways and in bus and train terminals. Pick two states.

Comment: @choster Thank you for your comment! Yes, in fact I don't have the ambition to visit all the states in New England. I'll be more than happy to just a couple of towns, maybe near to some natural reserve where I could hike a bit. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

[Cape Air](https://www.capeair.com/where_we_fly/New_England/new-england-flights.html) flies from Logan to a number of small airports. Some, like Nantucket, may be too touristy for you. But some of the others might suit you. You would have to look closely to see what can be reached on foot or by bus from the airport.